# php correct json numbers and strings encoding

Tags: php, json

I have a problem with encoding php array to json. Part of my data are stings like '555', '3M', part of data are numbers: floats or integers. On frontend I need to receive strings as strings and numbers as numbers as numbers for correct sorting, searching , etc. Php has a `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK`, but this will convert my sting '555' value into number. Is there any approach except first converting strings like strings, then numbers with  `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` option and then concatenating result?

Comment: send the json response as it is and later at front end you can convert them with javascript parse lib.

Comment: You can use the cast principale, (string) for strings and (int) for numbers

Comment: @ Ayyoub Dahhane could you please give an example?

Comment: @AyyoubDahhane ,can intval strval also be used..?

Comment: to parse a int ` $int = (int) $somevar;` you can replace int with string to parse strings

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = json_encode(['555', '3M', 123, 1.2, 1.3]);
var_dump($a);//outputs string(24) "["555","3M",123,1.2,1.3]"
```

Maybe you send data the wrong way. Try to see what you receive after your AJAX (POST method). Or read how correctly send data with AJAX. 
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem was with numbers. Because I queried numeric data from db, I received it as strings. So I converted string to numbers, and received correctly encoded data on frontend:

```
   array_walk_recursive($data, function(&$val) {
        if (is_numeric($val)) $val = (float) $val;
    });
```